# Url Routing for Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using ASP.Net MVC2 C# and I have a URL like below:

**http://localhost:2107/News/NewsHome/NewsDetails/Celebrate_the_dedication_of_healthcare_quality_professionals_during_National_Healthcare_Quality_Week**

Here News is Area and NewsHome is the controller but I want the URL to look like this

**http://localhost:2107/NewsDetails/Celebrate_the_dedication_of_healthcare_quality_professionals_during_National_Healthcare_Quality_Week**

Is there any option to get area and controller name from the URL?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a route like `"NewsDetails/{name}` and specify the area, controller and action in the `defaults` parameter (eg, `new { area = "News", controller = "NewsHome", action = "NewsDetails" }`).

If you define the route as `"{action}/{name}"`, it will swallow up all of your other routes too.

Answer (score 0):

Define a new Route

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "News", // Route name
        "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { area="News", controller = "NewsHome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```